# iAd causing major frame drop in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit, iad

I'm working on a SpriteKit game and usually everything is smooth as butter 60fps. Now I haven't worked on it for a month or so since I've been busy, but since coming back recently I noticed lots of dropped frames when playing.

I stripped everything back in my game and then started adding things back in until the dropped frames presented themselves. And it was actually adding the iAd ADBannerView in the same view controller as the SKView which caused the major frame drops.

I noticed Apple recently updated their demo 'iAd' would this cause this?

You can see the results below testing on an iPod Touch 5th Gen since this is where you can see the degradation best.

Anyone else noticed issues? I assume it's ok to add an ADBannerView and SKView to the same root view on a view controller? They aren't overlapping or anything.

Anyone know of anything I try to improve the performance (minus dropping the ads) :)

Cheers

[image: Performance Results]

Comment: Can you comment briefly on your view hierarchy? Is the `SKView` resized so that it and the iAd don't overlap?

Comment: I am having the same issues and thinking about it I think it did start when Apple changed the test iAd recently.

My iAd is loaded into the Main VC which like your code is shared by an SKView. The jitter appears to disappear when the iAd is removed and replaced by an Admob. Mmm.

I am currently investigating my code etc and will report back if I find the culprit. Hopefully some will chip in with the answer :)

Regards

paulh

Comment: Yes neither overlap and are both are children of a View Controller's view. I've reported the bug to Apple as others were having similar issues on Apple's Dev Forums. Lets see what they say. I've moved to AdMob until it's resolved.